# Identificar colunas vazias de um jTable e pintar toda a linha de Vermelho

Tags: java, swing, jtable

Estou fazendo a importação de um arquivo em Excel e jogando dentro de um jTable, ate ai tudo bem. O que acontece é que tem usuário inserindo planilha com campos vazios. Gostaria de deixar toda a lina em vermelho e solicitar que seja alterada.

Este é o código que uso pra importar a planilha para o jTable

```
    DefaultTableModel modeloTable = new DefaultTableModel();
   // ModeloTabela modeloTable = new ModeloTabela(null, col)
    try {
        //Recebe o arquivo da planilha
        XSSFWorkbook book = (XSSFWorkbook) WorkbookFactory.create(new FileInputStream(arquivo));
        //Pega a primeira folha da planilha
        Sheet folha = book.getSheetAt(0);
        //percorre as linhas da planilha
        Iterator linhaItetator = folha.rowIterator();
        //prepara o indice das linha para percorrer as celulas
        int indiceLinha = -1;

        tabela.setModel(modeloTable);

        while (linhaItetator.hasNext()) {
            indiceLinha++;

            Row linha = (Row) linhaItetator.next();

            Iterator colunaIterator = linha.cellIterator();

            int qtdColunas = linha.getLastCellNum();

            if (qtdColunas == -1) {
                break;
            }

            Object[] listaColuna = new Object[qtdColunas];

            int indiceColuna = -1;
            while (colunaIterator.hasNext()) {

                indiceColuna++;
                Cell celula = (Cell) colunaIterator.next();

                if (indiceLinha == 0) {
                    //ser for sem descrição a coluna, não vai ser criada
                    if (celula.getStringCellValue().equals("")) {
                        break;
                    }
                    modeloTable.addColumn(celula.getStringCellValue());
                } else {
                    if (celula != null) {

                        switch (celula.getCellType()) {

                            case Cell.CELL_TYPE_NUMERIC:
                                if (tipoImportacao == 0) {
                                    if (celula.getColumnIndex() == 3) {

                                        DateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy");
                                        listaColuna[indiceColuna] = df.format(celula.getDateCellValue());
                                        break;
                                    } else if (celula.getColumnIndex() == 4) {
                                        XSSFCellStyle celStyle = book.createCellStyle();
                                        XSSFDataFormat dataFor = book.createDataFormat();
                                        celStyle.setDataFormat(dataFor.getFormat("#,##0.00"));

                                        celula.setCellStyle(celStyle);

                                        listaColuna[indiceColuna] = celula.getNumericCellValue();
                                        break;
                                    }

                                    listaColuna[indiceColuna] = (int) celula.getNumericCellValue();
                                 //   System.out.println(celula.getNumericCellValue());
                                    break;
                                } else if (tipoImportacao == 1) {
                                    listaColuna[indiceColuna] = (int) celula.getNumericCellValue();
                                //    System.out.println(celula.getNumericCellValue());
                                    break;
                                }
                                listaColuna[indiceColuna] = (int) celula.getNumericCellValue();
                                break;

                            case Cell.CELL_TYPE_STRING:
                                listaColuna[indiceColuna] = celula.getStringCellValue();
                             //   System.out.println(celula.getStringCellValue());
                                break;

                            case Cell.CELL_TYPE_BOOLEAN:
                                listaColuna[indiceColuna] = celula.getBooleanCellValue();
                             //   System.out.println(celula.getBooleanCellValue());
                                break;

                            case Cell.CELL_TYPE_FORMULA:
                                listaColuna[indiceColuna] = celula.getCellFormula();
                             //   System.out.println(celula.getCellFormula());
                                break;

                            case Cell.CELL_TYPE_BLANK:
                                //caso seja uma linha em branco não sera apresentada na tabela  

                                if (indiceColuna == 0) {
                                    flagVazio = 1;
                                }

                                break;

                            case Cell.CELL_TYPE_ERROR:
                                break;
                            default:

                                break;
                        }
                    }
                }

            }//fim do iterator coluna

            if (flagVazio == 1) {
                indiceLinha--;
                flagVazio = 0;

            } else if (indiceLinha != 0) {
                modeloTable.addRow(listaColuna);
            }
        }//fim do iterator linha
```

Como podem ver nesse código estou usando o DefaultTableModel pois não consegui filtrar os "case" para data, valor dentre outras coisas.

O tipo de planilha que recebo é

[image: Planilha que é lida pelo código]

Como a tabela é editável, para evitar do usuário voltar no Excel, digitar o que está faltando e depois tentar novamente eu gostaria de deixar as linhas com erro em vermelho.

Comment: Olhando melhor o seu código, você não deveria tratar isso na tabela, e sim, antes de inserir nela, como está fazendo o case. Talvez seja o caso de interromper o restante da inserção e informar ao usuario que a planilha contem linhas em branco e não concluir a importação.

Comment: Caso prefira fazer isso após a importação, deixando os campos salientados de vermelho(o que pode ser ignorado pelo usuario), ai é com CellRenderer mesmo, mas pra isso seria necessário um [mcve] da sua JTable e do TableModel dela.

Comment: O que tinha pensando é, que enquanto todas as linhas vermelhas não fossem corrigidas não se poderia dar o próximo passo. Vou melhorar a pergunta e especificar isso.

Comment: Acho que isso iria tornar complexa demais a aplicação, se você souber trabalhar com threads, boa sorte, é uma boa alternativa. Se não, talvez seja melhor verificar isso antes de popular a tabela, e informar ao usuário que há celulas vazias e não concluir a operação.